# cant open web UI status page for the SecondaryNameNode

Tags: hadoop

I have set up a small Hadoop cluster with 3 machines:

1. Machine (Hadoop1) is running both NameNode and Jobtracker
2. Machine(Hadoop2) is running SecondaryNameNode
3. Machine(Hadoop3) is running DataNode and TaskTracker

Everthing works well when I checked the Log files. 
However, when I tried to check working status of the SecondaryNameNode by typing localhost:50090 on the machine Hadoop2, it shows:

```
Unable to connect ....can't establish a connection to the server at localhost:50090.
```

Anyone ever met this kind of problem?

**contents in the hdfs-site.xml on SNN:**

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>dfs.replication</name>
<value>2</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>dfs.http.address</name>
<value>Hadoop1:50070</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>dfs.secondary.http.address</name>
<value>Hadoop2:50090</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

**Below is part of running log from SNN:**

```
2013-04-23 19:47:00,820 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Number of transactions: 0 Total time for transactions(ms): 0Number of transactions batched in Syncs: 0 Number of syncs: 0 SyncTimes(ms): 0
2013-04-23 19:47:00,987 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode: Downloaded file fsimage size 654 bytes.
2013-04-23 19:47:00,989 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode: Downloaded file edits size 4 bytes.
2013-04-23 19:47:00,989 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
2013-04-23 19:47:00,989 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: 2% max memory = 17.77875 MB
2013-04-23 19:47:00,989 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: capacity      = 2^21 = 2097152 entries
2013-04-23 19:47:00,989 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: recommended=2097152, actual=2097152
2013-04-23 19:47:00,998 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: fsOwner=hadoop
2013-04-23 19:47:00,998 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: supergroup=supergroup
2013-04-23 19:47:00,998 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: isPermissionEnabled=true
2013-04-23 19:47:00,998 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.block.invalidate.limit=100
2013-04-23 19:47:00,999 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: isAccessTokenEnabled=false accessKeyUpdateInterval=0 min(s), accessTokenLifetime=0 min(s)
2013-04-23 19:47:00,999 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: Caching file names occuring more than 10 times
2013-04-23 19:47:00,999 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Number of files = 7
2013-04-23 19:47:01,000 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Number of files under construction = 0
2013-04-23 19:47:01,000 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Edits file /app/hadoop/tmp/dfs/namesecondary/current/edits of size 4 edits # 0 loaded in 0 seconds.
2013-04-23 19:47:01,001 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Number of transactions: 0 Total time for transactions(ms): 0Number of transactions batched in Syncs: 0 Number of syncs: 0 SyncTimes(ms): 0
2013-04-23 19:47:01,049 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Image file of size 654 saved in 0 seconds.
2013-04-23 19:47:01,334 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Image file of size 654 saved in 0 seconds.
2013-04-23 19:47:01,570 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode: Posted URL Hadoop1:50070putimage=1&port=50090&machine=Hadoop3&token=-32:145975115:0:1366717621000:1366714020860
2013-04-23 19:47:01,771 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode: Checkpoint done. New Image Size: 654
```

Answer (score 0):

Try giving value to dfs.secondary.http.address in hdfs-site.xml on your SNN. Also, I am assuming you have no firewall enabled between your machines right? It would help if you can show your logs, I have seen sometimes users enter the incorrect port number for the SNN which differs in their logs and hence gives connection errors.

Comment: dfs.secondary.http.address was already set in the file hdfs-site.xml on the SNN, and I just posted the content of file hdfs-site.xml, as above shows. Also I posted the log of SNN, which shows it worked well and the checkpoints have been done successfully.